# Django rest framework "Var must be a User Instance" vs "Object of type 'type' is not JSON serializable"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to serialize a model having a foreign key "User".
The concerned view snippet is:

```
  data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = SiteSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        userid = data['supervisor']

        user = User.objects.get(id=userid).__dict__ ## tried case I 
        user = User.objects.get(id=userid) ## tried case II
        serializer.save(supervisor=user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
```

The serializer is as :

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
supervisor = serializers.RelatedField(source='User', read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ('sitename', 'start_date', 'supervisor')
```

The model is :

```
class Site(models.Model):
sitename=models.CharField(max_length=255)
start_date=models.DateTimeField
supervisor=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.sitename)
```

When I pass supervisor object it says that object of type "Type" is not serializable and when I pass supervisor as dictionary it says that the dict variable supervisor must be a User instance.
How do I sort this out and proceed??

Comment: Why are you using `data = JSONParser().parse(request)` instead of using `serializer = SiteSerializer(data=request.data)` directly?

Comment: This line `start_date=models.DateTimeField` (class) must be `start_date=models.DateTimeField()` (instance)

Comment: @DaniloAkamine I tried your suggestion in first comment and it gives error as `{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got WSGIRequest."]}` meaning the `serializer.is_valid()` fails upon doing so.  The thing you mentioned in the second comment, thank you for pointing it out. It had gone out of sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRF handles most of the data parsing itself and the parsed data can be found in **`request.data`** attribute.

```
# serializers.py
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supervisor = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True) # remove "source argument "

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('sitename', 'start_date', 'supervisor')


#views.py
from rest_framework.response import Response # use DRF's response class


class Foo(APIView):
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = SiteSerializer(data=request.data) # use "request.data"
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(supervisor=request.user) # pass user instance directly to the serializer/model saving flow using "request.user"
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors) # show validation errors if any
```